# how to compare elements in lists

Tags: python

How can I store values in lists and later compare against each other

```
all_click = []                                            
all_click_red = []



while True:

    a = input('give a number: ')                          
    b = input('give a second number: ')

    if a == 1:
        all_click.append(a)                               

    if b == 1:                                            
        all_click_red.append(b)                           

    if all_click_red[-1] and all_click[-1] == 1:          
        print('all good')                                 

    else:                                                 
        print('false')
```

Because I get an error like this:

```
 if all_click_red[-1] and all_click[-1] == 1:
     IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: `all_click_red[-1] and all_click[-1] == 1` should be `all_click_red[-1] == all_click[-1] == 1`, and your lists could be empty: in your case, one of ths lists _is_ empty. Please no interactve reproducer.

Comment: What's gonna happen if `a != 1` or `b != 1`? Hint: one or two of the lists is going to be empty, and an empty list doesn't have a last element.

Comment: @cricket_007 it's a multi-duplicate, of the one you're quoting + "how to test against multiple values" + "list index out of range"... OP has to read a python book....

Comment: yeah that one exactly...

Comment: @Jean the error is caused by the first one :)

Comment: doesn't really solve OP issue, but yeah, everything in the links is related to OP numerous problems. I won't reopen :)

Comment: use int(input) and if all_click_red[0] and all_click[0] == 1:

Comment: Oh great... that was a waste of an answer

Answer (score 0):

The reason for that is that one of the lists may not have a value in it.

You'll probably want something like this:

```
if len(all_click) > 0 and len(all_click_red) > 0 and all_click_red[-1] == 1 and all_click[-1] == 1:          
    print('all good')                                 

else:                                                 
    print('false')
```

Never hurts to check for index safety when accessing indexes in a list like this.

I also added an equality on the all_click_red number check. I'm assuming that's what you were after. Apologies if I misjudged

Answer (score 0):

You are append something to the list only if it's value is equal 1. If it's not equal 1, the list is empty, and list[-1] will be out of range, raising this error.